# In some of my VMs grep does not show color. Is there any shorter switch for `grep --color`?

Tags: linux, grep

I have to ssh login to so many VMs / containers.

In some of my VMs `grep` does not show color. Is there any `grep` default settings?

Is there any shorter version of `grep --color` switch?

Answer (score 1):

Where `grep` does show color by default, it most likely does this because of an alias defined as:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

When a new regular user is created, some Linux distros automatically set up proper files in the user's home directory, so the alias works for the user out of the box in the default login shell.

AFAIK there is no shorter version of the `--color` option. Permanently defining the alias in VMs/accounts/shells where it's missing may be the best solution. You said nothing about distros involved and their implementations of `grep`. Keep in mind that a particular implementation of `grep` may or may not support `--color` in the first place. Still, where `grep --color=auto` works for you when typed manually, the alias should work as well.

The way to permanently define an alias depends on the shell. For Bash see this link: [*How do I create a permanent Bash alias?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/693277)